# why multiple conditions on ng-if shows this error with angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to check if events length is 0 and term.length if greater than 2 with the following code,

```
 <li class="more-result" *ngIf="events?.length == 0" && "term.value.length > 2">
              <span class="tab-content-area-active-location">          
                  No events found in {{selectedCountry}}
               </span>
 </li
```

>

it shows a template error on console as,

```
Unexpected closing tag "li" ("
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **ngIf** condition from

```
*ngIf="events?.length == 0" && "term.value.length > 2"
```

to

```
*ngIf="events?.length == 0 && term.value.length > 2"
```

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: events?.length == 0 &&  at the end of the expression [events?.length == 0 && ]